# Validating input with isdigit for a factorial program

Tags: c

I wrote the following code in C to make a program which calculate the factorial of any number.

I want to add to my program some validation/error handling, such as preventing random characters, floats or negative values from being entered, so I used the `isdigit` function.

Unfortunately there is a hidden problem which I don't know how to solve. When I enter any input it considers it to be false (i.e. not a digit) even if it's a positive digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    unsigned long long int factorial=1;
    int counter,number;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Please , enter a positive integer number only : ");
        scanf("%d",&number);
        fflush(stdin);
        if(isdigit(number))
        {
            for(counter=number;counter>1;counter--)
            factorial*=counter;
            printf("The factorial of number %d is %llu",number,factorial);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\a\aError\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("\n1-Press c or C if you want to calculate the factorial of a new number\n2-Press any key         if you want to exit the program\n ");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        if(choice=='c'||choice=='C')
        {
            factorial=1;
            system("cls");
            continue;
        }
        else
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that 12! is the largest value that fits in a 32-bit (unsigned) integer, and 20! is the largest value that fits in a 64-bit (unsigned) integer.

Comment: In addition to the answers, suggest dropping the `fflush(stdin)` and changing `scanf("%c",&choice);` to `scanf(" %c",&choice);` (add space).  This will consume optional leading white-space including the previous lines <Enter>.

Answer (score 1):

You are using isdigit wrong. Read its documentation to find out what it actually does.

You probably meant:

```
 if ( number >= 0 && number <= 9 )
```

However you also need to check whether scanf succeeded or not. If they type in some words, then `scanf("%d"` fails and does not update `number`, so trying to access `number` in that case accesses an uninitialized variable. To deal with that you could either check the return value of `scanf`, or do:

```
int number = -1;
scanf("%d",&number);
```

because the value will be left unchanged if the input failed.

NB. [Don't use fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: Note that if the platform is Windows, `fflush(stdin)` is perfectly well defined.  If the platform is not Windows, it is a problem.

Comment: [O Really!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin#comment31066899_2979209) — relevant link for MS in the comment referenced.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that links is to MSVC documentation . It suggests that "the operating system" "usually" does the buffering but clearly there are cases where fflush(stdin) doesn't work in Windows. Especially if you are not programming in a commode!

Comment: What do commodes have to do with Windows, other than being where you should put machines that run Windows?  I'm not sure what you're driving at; the MSVC manual for [`fflush()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) says _If the stream is open for input, fflush clears the contents of the buffer._  There isn't any wriggle room or iffery in that statement.  It isn't even tied to `stdin`; it is any input stream.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The MSVC manual should be taken to document the behaviour of MSVC , not other compilers

Comment: OK; correction accepted; using the libraries provided with MSVC on Windows…

Answer (score 0):

isdigit checks a single character if that's a decimal digit character.
But, your input could be say 25, multiple characters. So, I changed a portion:L

```
 char input[30];
 for(;;)
 {
  printf("Please , enter a positive integer number only : ");
  scanf("%s",input);
  if(isdigit(input[0]))
  {
   number = atoi(input);
   for(counter=number;counter>1;counter--)
```

Keeping rest of your program snippet same.
Here, isdigit is used to check if the first character in input is a digit and therefore a valid candidate to be converted by atoi into an integer value number.

Comment: Do **not** use `fflush(stdin);` to flush the input buffer -- it does **not** do what you think it does. Instead declare and `int c;` and then place the following line after each `scanf` handling string input: `do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);`. That will remove all remaining characters from the input buffer. Prove it to yourself. Enter: `1 2 3` in the code above. It will loop 3 times never pausing after 'printf`.